# Where in clojurescript is the .strobj function defined?

Tags: clojurescript

Where in clojurescript is the .strobj function defined?

I have tried

```
ack -a  "strobj"
```

on the whole project, but no function definition returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strobj is not a function but a field of ObjMap instances. You shouldn't use it directly.

Comment: I thought I use it for converting cljs maps to js maps. 
What is the right way of such conversion then? All methods for doing that use .strobj, including e.g. clj->js at http://mmcgrana.github.com/2011/09/clojurescript-nodejs.html

Comment: There is no provided general conversion function (though there probably should be)

Comment: @dnolen If not calling it directly or using a conversion function, what is the alternative? I am following [this tutorial](http://mmcgrana.github.io/2011/09/clojurescript-nodejs.html) and `.strobj` is being called directly. It is causing me this error:

`TypeError: Object {"Content-Type" "text/plain"} has no method 'strobj'`

Comment: nm, apparently you can just use js-obj and get rid of the curly braces.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037755/clojurescript-converting-cljs-map-to-a-javascript-hash

Comment: Now, the function clj->js exists in [clj.core](https://crossclj.info/fun/cljs.core.cljs/js->clj.html).