# Clojurescript: converting cljs map to a javascript hash

Tags: clojurescript

### The following code snippet does not work

```
     headerElement (goog.dom/createDom
                    "div" (.strobj {"style" "background-color:#EEE"})
                    (:title note))
```

### Reason:

{ ... } creates a Clojurescript map. I need a javascript object/hash.

### Question:

How do I make this trivial conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cljs.core/js-obj should help for this. Please notice that it takes normal array/list in (not a map).

```
headerElement (goog.dom/createDom
               "div" (js-obj "style" "background-color:#EEE")
               (:title note))
```

Comment: Awesome. Relatively quick way to do this using a map: (apply js-obj (apply concat (seq map))))

Answer (score 13):

You can also use `#js` reader literal to create JavaScript object or array.

You can write:

```
(def test1 #js {:foo 1 :bar false})
```

which creates JavaScript code:

```
namespace.test1 = {"bar":false, "foo":1};
```

For array:

```
(def test2 #js [1 2 3 false nil true])
```

creates:

```
namespace.test2 = [1, 2, 3, false, null, true];
```

You can also use `clj->js` function:

```
(clj->js :style "background-color:#EEE")
```

the nice thing about it is that it works recursively - converting nested data structures.

I made a [post](http://www.spacjer.com/blog/2014/09/12/clojurescript-javascript-interop/) about it (if I can advertise myself)

Answer (score 1):

This macro will let you use `js-obj` with keywords:

**Macro**

```
(defmacro obj [& key-values]
(let [obj-def (apply concat (map #(list (name (first %)) (last %))
     (partition 2 key-values)))]
    `(cljs.core/js-obj ~@obj-def)
))
```

**Usage**

```
(obj 
    :key someVal
    :otherKey (fn [a b] a)
)
```